# tableone package : How to get the odds ratio and the confidence interval from a svydesign object?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, propensity-score-matching

I routinely use the 'weightit' package for propensity score , then I use the 'tableone' package to compare my variables after adjustment.

For exemple,

`wgt = weightit(formula = var ~ var1 + var2 +var3 , data = df, method = "ps",estimand = "ATO" )`

'var' is a binary variable

`design <- svydesign(~1, weights = wgt$weights, data = df)`

`tabel <- svyCreateTableOne(vars=  list_var   ,strata = "var", data = design)`

This gives me a table with the mean values (or percentage) with the p-value.

How is it possible to get the confidence interval for each variable from a svydesign object ? And how is it possible to obtain the odds ratio as well as the p-value and the confidence interval of the odds ratio

I would like to get a result like this :

[non adjusted vs adjusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn1Ma.png)

Comment: You shouldn't do this. You should not report p-values in balance tables. See the `cobalt` [vignette](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/articles/cobalt.html#test-statistics-and-p-values) for reasons why not. Odds ratios provide no more additional information than mean differences but are hard to interpret, so I'm not sure why you want them either. You should use standardized mean differences as recommended in most papers on balance and implemented in `tableone` and `cobalt`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I think I misspoke because I was looking for ORs and ICs for unadjusted variables (e.g. for comparison of treatment effect). I ask this because some reviewers require them. Is it possible with 'weightit'?

Comment: I see. `tableone` is for assessing balance, not for displaying treatment effects. To estimate treatment effects, you will have to do so one outcome at a time using logistic regression and then create the table manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but to estimate the treatment effect, is it correct to use svyglm or glm (binomial) function in the context of an overlap propensity score ('ATO') as per this tutorial which used 'ATT' (https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/articles/WeightIt.html)?

Comment: Yes, that works for any kinds of weights.